# pysparkshell works, but not python -> pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a problem with pyspark. I am able to run my cluster when I boot up pysparkshell from the command line aka:

```
pyspark --total-executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 3g
```

but when I run python and try to boot up the cluster using the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

conf = SparkConf() \
.setAppName('PySparkShell') \
.setMaster('url_to_cluster') \
.set('spark.executor.memory', '2g') \
.set('spark.cores.max', '6') \
.set('spark.sql.catalogImplementation', 'hive') \
.set('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
.set('spark.executor.id', 'driver') \
.set('spark.rdd.compress', 'True') \
.set('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100') \
.set('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true')

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

I get the following issue:

```
ERROR TransportRequestHandler:193 - Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 6381742667596359353
    java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerId; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6155820641931972170, local class serialVersionUID = -3720498261147521052
```

anybody have experience with this? I cannot find another issue like this one online

Comment: Are the spark versions on all the places same?